# Having trouble parsing itunes affiliate xml

Tags: iphone, objective-c, itunes, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse an itunes affiliate xml link purely for practise, using NSXMLParser but the link will not parse. The itunes affiliate xml link is this: `http://itunes.apple.com/au/rss/topsongs/limit=50/genre=20/xml?partnerId=2003&TD_PARAM=http%3A%2F%2Fclkuk.tradedoubler.com%2Fclick%3Fp%3D23708%26a%3D1904172%26url%3D`.

it works perfectly in safari on my mac. The normal itunes link I tried parsing:

`http://itunes.apple.com/au/rss/topsongs/limit=50/genre=20/xml`

works perfectly with the NSXMLParser. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Thanks in advanced.

MKDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, NSXMLParse has some problems, so it can be the bug in it.
What error do you receive?

Comment: error parsing XML: Unable to download news feed from the web site (Error code 5 )

Comment: It tells for itself - it could be connectivity error or so on. That feed is quite long.

Comment: Maybe, first to download XML into NSData and after that run NSXMLParser?